# Cannot find name 'java'

Tags: angular, nativescript

I installed a plugin that requires to use native APIs so when I placed the code I received the following error:

```
"message": "Cannot find name 'java'."
```

I tried "tns platform remove android" and "tns run android"
but that still didn't remove the error.

Here is my code:

```
 private _getSize(path: string): string {
    let length: number = 0;
    if (isAndroid) {
      const file = new java.io.File(path);
      length = file.length();
    }
    return `${(length / (1000 * 1000)).toFixed(2)} MB`;
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sounds like TypeScript declaration issue. Simply place

```
declare var java: any;
```

at top of the file. Or you could use [tns-platform-declarations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tns-platform-declarations) if you like IntelliSense support.